# Control in UpdatePanel not found using $find

Tags: asp.net, telerik, updatepanel

I have a complicated page but I created a simple ASP.NET page with the issue. I have telerik RadAsyncUpload control and a button inside an UpdatePanel as shown:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="_updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    ...
    <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" MaxFileInputsCount="1"  OnClientFilesSelected="fileUpload_ClientFilesSelected" /><br />         

    <asp:Button ID="_saveNewFileButton" runat="server" OnClick="_saveNewFileButton_Click"
    Text="Save"/>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When a file is selected I want to disable the _saveNewFileButton and change the text to "Please Wait for Attachment Upload..." but I can't seem to get hold of the button reference in javascript:

```
var FilesUpdateInterval = null;

 //Handles client side FilesSelected event for _newFileUploadButton.
 function fileUpload_ClientFilesSelected(sender, args) {
     //disable the click event for submit button during upload
     var submitButton = $find('<%= _saveNewFileButton.ClientID %>');
     submitButton.set_text('Please Wait for Attachment Upload...')
     submitButton.set_readOnly(true);
     if (FilesUpdateInterval == null) {
         FilesUpdateInterval = setInterval(function () { FileCheckForUploadCompletion(); }, 500);
     }
 }
```

I am getting submitButton is null error. I tried putting this javascript code outside the updatepanel and inside ContentTemplate with same result. Obviously whatever I am doing is wrong. How do I get hold of the control that is in updatepanel in javascript?

EDIT: I find out that $find works with only telerik controls. So, I have to either use document.getElementById function or JQuery with something like Steve specified. Also, I have to use RegisterClientScriptBlock. I will test with Steve suggestion and then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short version - use $get() or document.getElementById(), as regular HTML elements are not IScriptControls, so $find() will not give you anything, and they don't have the rich client API you are trying to use.

For example

```
            var submitButton = $get('<%= _saveNewFileButton.ClientID %>');
            submitButton.setAttribute("value", "Please Wait for Attachment Upload...");
```

Option 2 - use RadButton.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. My bad, I copy pasted from different location with RadButton and expected it to work, with out thinking through.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and vb with ASP.Net, I've done something similar to this, which has worked well, even if it isn't that pretty.  The [Whatever] I have was a FormView that didn't always have the control.  Also, I didn't use it with a button, but I think that's the syntax for changing the button text.  Either way, it might give you some ideas:

```
$('#<%=GetButtonClientID("_saveNewFileButton")%>').attr('value', 'Please Wait for Attachment Upload...');
```

And then I have a function like this:

```
Public Function GetButtonClientID(ByVal argFieldName As String) As String

    Dim tmpID As String = "0"

    Dim tmpButton As Button = [Whatever].FindControl(argFieldName)
    If Not tmpButton Is Nothing Then Return tmpButton.ClientID.ToString Else Return "0"


End Function
```